# C# repository Generic with custom queries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, repository-pattern, dry

I currently have a method that allows me to generate an IEnumerable object for my dropdown list in my web app forms.

Example of current code :

```
//Name with Id 
StateListDp = _db.States.ToDropdownList(c => c.Name, c => Convert.ToString(c.Id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

//Description with Id
StatusesListDp = _db.Statuses.ToDropdownList(c => c.Description, c => Convert.ToString(c.Id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

I've just implemented Repository Design Pattern.

I'm able to convert it over to this now :

```
StateListDp = unitOfWork.State.GetDropDownList().ToList();
StatusesListDp = unitOfWork.Status.GetDropDownList().ToList();
```

I've created the following support class (I've excluded the unitOfWork for now )

```
public class StatusRepository : Repository<Statuses>, IStatusRepository
{
    private readonly TenDDbContext context;

    public StatusRepository(TenDDbContext context): base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Statuses> GetAllActive()
    {
        return Find(x => x.IsActive == true);
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDropDownList()
    {
        return GetAllActive()
            .ToDropdownList(c => c.Description, c => Convert.ToString(c.Id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
public class StateRepository : Repository<States>, IStateRepository
{
    private readonly TenDDbContext context;

    public StateRepository(TenDDbContext context): base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<States> FindAllActive(Expression<Func<States, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Find(predicate).Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
    }

    public IEnumerable<States> GetAllActive()
    {
        return Find(x => x.IsActive == true);
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDropDownList()
    {
        return GetAllActive()
            .ToDropdownList(c => c.Name, c => Convert.ToString(c.Id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly TenDDbContext context;

    public Repository(TenDDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity).Entity;
    }

    //public bool save(TEntity entity)
    //{
    // var test=   Add(entity);
    //    test.
    //}

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        //context.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //  context.Attach(entity);
        //return   context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        return context.Update(entity)
           .Entity;
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
    }
}
```

So my issue is that I have 10 or so tables that I will need to retrieve this very similar data from.

I'm wondering there is a way to make the GetDropDownList a generic method?

So that I can limit the amount of repeat code ...

I'm even willing to make it two methods

GetDropDownNameList  and GetDropDownDescriptionList

adding dropdownextension method

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToDropdownList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items,
                Func<T, string> text, Func<T, string> value = null, Func<T, Boolean> selected = null)
{
    var listData = items.Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = text.Invoke(p),
        Value = (value == null ? text.Invoke(p) : value.Invoke(p)),
                Selected = selected != null && selected.Invoke(p)
    });
    var defaultRow = new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "Please Select One", Selected = V };
    var newList = listData.Prepend(defaultRow);
    //return new SelectList(newList, "Value", "Text");
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Do they have the same properties? For an example, all tables have the field Name and Description

Comment: Not all tables have the name or description fields only select ones.

Comment: You would need theses tables to have the same field names, in this case, Name or Description, so you could go with generics + constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing the selection of the props for description and key should do the trick. If you want to make it even more generic to be inside the IRepository, replace GetAllActive() with a filter

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDropDownList(Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> predicateDescription, Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> predicateKey)
    {
        return GetAllActive().ToDropdownList(predicateDescription, predicateKey);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I seem to be running into another issue with my todropdown extension method now :). I've add code snippet above I'm trying to figure who have the system.linq.expression work with the system.func

Comment: Figured it out thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!